# Encouraging users to invite team members

Tags: signup-signon, trust, team

We're currently rebuilding our on-boarding process...

Our tool is a team solution and the user only sees the real benefit when their team is connected to our product.

What are some good methods to encourage users to invite their team?

Things we have already tried:

- Free flow text input asking user to type emails separated by commas.
- Giving the option of team vs individual plan (team plan being default and wording strongly suggesting this is the recommended plan)
- Basic bullets explaining the benefits of creating a team.

Our users connect their email account to our product, so we are (in some cases) able to identity users who share the same email domain, we're thinking of either automatically suggesting who they should add, allowing the user to simply un-tick the ones they don't want to invite, or automatically inviting all users who have that email domain. I know Path did something similar to this and got some bad press but...

We want to be more bold in how we approach this because we know our tool is more valuable when the team is connected.

We will also try to encourage users to invite team members when they are using the product, this will come later.

Any ideas/war stories welcome...

Comment: Right now the question is really open ended and basically asking us to design possible solutions. Is there an actual problem, i.e. did some of the things you tried not work?

Answer (score 0):

Competition and/or prizes are a long standing motivator. There has been some research suggesting high cash prizes are not overly engaging.

A quick search turns up this page http://intenseminimalism.com/2012/the-misconception-about-money-and-motivation/ that highlights some motivators misconceptions.

Comment: It's called **gamification** and yes it works! But the gamification has more weapon beyond rewards so it worth more learning.

Comment: Gamification is actually a specific form of incentivization, and unfortunately a form that has been hyped and abused quite badly. Yes, gamification refers to specific kinds of motivations, but it's a very narrow view on the field of motivation. You can start with the page on "Motivation" on wikipedia and you'll get a lot of more proper material to read. Or if you want something about game mechanics applied to non-games, check Jane McGonigal.

Answer (score 0):

What about a demo of all that your product could be with a team on board? Perhaps even a few, each for a different kind of user. You already have some information up on why creating a team is good; now that has to be made concrete.